# My .exe clears Event Viewer logs when I run it manually on the command line, but not when I call it from my C# code

Tags: c#, .net, process, console, psexec

I have a tool for clearing the Windows Event Viewer system logs. I can call this tool on the command line by doing EventViewer.exe -args where -args is the command I want to run. For example, if I want to clear the logs I can replace -args with "clear" and it will clear the system's logs. In this case, I've hardcoded EventViewer.exe to clear a specific remote machine's logs. Basically, I sign into machine A. On machine A, I run EventViewer.exe clear from the command line and it clears machine B's logs.

The problem is that running my C# code on machine A doesn't run EventViewer.exe properly. I'm trying to start a process that kicks off EventViewer.exe with the "clear" argument. It opens the console window and shows that it starts to execute, but it seems to close before it's done executing. Here is the method inside EventViewer.exe that clears the logs:

```
private static void clear()
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\Testing\PsExec.exe", "\\\\192.168.1.200 -u Administrator -p \"\" C:\\Testing\\EventViewer.exe -clear System");
}
```

When I do EventViewer.exe clear on the command line, this method gets triggered and it runs perfectly. It clears that machine's system log entries. That is machine B. But when I run some C# code on machine A, it doesn't work the same as when I manually execute that exe via the command line. Here is the C# code that I'm trying to run on machine A.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Testing\EventViewer.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "clear";
proc.Start();
```

I've also tried running it like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Testing\EventViewer.exe", "clear");
```

But it doesn't work. A console window opens up, I can see that it's trying to connect to \192.168.1.200 as it normally does when I run the command manually, but then it stops and the rest of my code executes and does unrelated stuff. Any idea what's wrong? Why can't I fully execute the .exe as a process with that argument?

Edit: After a closer look, it says "Access is denied" and then the console closes. This happens when EventViewer.exe is executed from inside code. But when I execute it manually, it executes just fine...

Comment: Try running as admin?

Comment: @Jacobr365 I've tried running it as admin, no luck. I did proc.UseShellExecute = true and proc.Verb = "runas" and it didn't make a difference. I think that's how you get it to run as Admin, right?

Comment: try putting the .exe in the same folder as the c# program.

Comment: @Jacobr365 I can look into doing that, but I don't think it will matter. The code starts executing PsExec properly but then PsExec claims that access was denied. Why would placing the EventViewer.exe in the same folder change that?

Comment: Depending on your c# code it may not have permission to get to the .exe.

Comment: You were right about executing as Admin. Just tried it again after cleaning up my code some more. I'm pretty sure that was the problem. I had initially tried that using just ProcessStartInfo's verb field, but I should've passed in a username and a password for the host system as well. (I also tried changing a setting in order to allow unsafe code but I don't think that matters in this case)

Comment: Glad to know I could help.